# Как в боте отредактировать сообщение с фото на другое фото?

Tags: python, изображения, telegram, telebot

Возникла данная проблема: необходимо фото в сообщении заменить на другое фото.
Пытался так:

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=msg_chat_id,
    message_id=msg_id, text=open('frame.jpg', 'rb'))`
```

P.S. `msg_chat_id` и `msg_id` нормальные переменные

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,
"description":"Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit"}']"
```

Как это решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть прекрасный метод [editMessageMedia](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagemedia):

```py
with open('frame.jpg', 'rb') as file
    photo = types.InputMediaPhoto(file)

bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=msg_chat_id, message_id=msg_id, media=photo)
```

Ну или так:

```py
with open('frame.jpg', 'rb') as file
    bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=msg_chat_id, message_id=msg_id, media=types.InputMediaPhoto(file))
```

Comment: а файл кто будет закрывать?:)

Comment: Точно... Спасибо большое за замечание :)