# Как в aigram отредактировать сообщение поменяв фото

Tags: python, aiogram

Я редактирую сообщение так:
await call.message.edit_text(**text**, reply_markup=**keyboard**)

Но в моём сообщении есть фото. Каким методом нужно его отредактировать **заменив фото, текст и кнопки**?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже дан [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1307557). Для aiogram это будет выглядеть вот так:

```py
with open('frame.jpg', 'rb') as file
    photo = types.InputMediaPhoto(file, caption="New text")

await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=msg_chat_id, message_id=msg_id, media=photo, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Но в таком случае текст нельзя отредактировать?
Он стирается, а дополнительным методом нельзя, ибо пишет ошибку, что текста для редактирования нет

Comment: Ваш текст, это caption в объекте types.InputMediaPhoto(). Обновил ответ